# Stacked Column two values per column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Is there a way in highcharts to stack columns that have two values per column. Incomplete vs Completed projects  What I want to have is one column for Aaron that has the incomplete and completed values, then the next column for Johns Team with incomplete and completed values? Thanks in advance for your help 
My code is below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Complete vs Incomplete Tasks (by Team)'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Aarons Team' /*,'Johns Team' */ ]
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Tasks'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Aarons Team',
        data: [4]
      }, //incomplete projects
      {
        name: 'Aarons Team',
        data: [2]
      } // completed projects
      /* {name: 'Johns Team', data:[6]},              //incompleted projects
         {name: 'Johns Team', data:[4]}               // completed projects
       */

    ]

  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: next time please click the `<>` in the editor to create a [mcve]

Comment: See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/) it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
You for each extra column you have to place 0 or NULL for the previous column.

```
     { name: 'Aarons Team', data:[4] },  //incomplete projects
        { name: 'Aarons Team', data:[2]}    // completed projects
         {name: 'Johns Team', data:[0,6]},              //incompleted projects
         {name: 'Johns Team', data:[0,4]}               // completed projects
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're asking for is the basic functionality of a stacked column chart.

You can set it up like this:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Aaron','John']
},
series: [{
  name: 'Complete',
  data: [5,7]
}, {
  name: 'Incomplete',
  data: [8,9]
}]
```

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/206/

**Output:**

[image]